# What does Scala mean by Suspicious Type Shadowing?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm implementing a scala Set, and I'm getting this error from this code

```
Suspicious shadowing by a Type Parameter: A
```

```scala
def remove[A](elemToRemove: A): MySet[A]
           ^
```

which for some reason, the language hates this generic A I'm passing it, why is that? and what does it mean by "Suspicious shadonwing"?

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NwcMObgnSxGjXA2clmaEyA, though scastie is running into a different error, if you remove the `[A]` from `remove[A]` it will pass and execute

```
type mismatch;
 found   : exercises.part2afp.MySet[A(in class NonEmptySet)]
 required: exercises.part2afp.MySet[A(in method remove)]
```

Comment: Because you probably already defined `A` at the class level, and you probably want to refer to the same `A`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I haven't really, this is within the type class

Comment: Can you create an **Scastie** that reproduces the message?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Added, though the error appears different and its no longer giving me the syntax error

Comment: Hint: Why should the type parameters for `apply` and `remove` be different?

Comment: @user2167582 well, just as I said, you already have defined `A` at the class / trait / interface / type / container level; that is what the warning says that you are shadowing that type which is usually a bad idea; even more, in this case, you not only don't want to shadow that one but you don't even want to have a new type parameter, just remove the `[A]`  from `remove`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what's the harm in adding that [A] type? isn't that still valid?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  Ah ok, nvm I think I see it, thanks :)

Comment: @user2167582 It's still valid, but with different meaning. E.g. you can have `val set: MySet[Int] = ???; set.remove("x")` (inferred to be `remove[String]`). If you remove the type parameter from `remove`, the second line will not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the context:

```
case class EmptySet[A]() extends MySet[A] {
  override def remove[A](elemToRemove: A): MySet[A] = this
```

The problem is that the `A` in `remove[A]` is a different type from the `A` in `EmptySet[A]`.

If you want these to be different types, use different letters.

If it is supposed to be the same type, delete the `[A]` from `remove`.